# .NET Core app on Heroku: Web process failed to bind to $PORT, how to fix?

Tags: heroku, asp.net-core, deployment

I deployed my asp.net core app to heroku using git. It deployed just fine, but it crushes after a minute with this error:

Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

I googled it, but found only solutions for other platforms, not .net core. How can I fix this error?

I tried doing this, but it did not work

```
    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseUrls("http://+:" + System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PORT"));

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This woked for me, finally!!!

```
    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseKestrel(options =>
            {
                options.ListenAnyIP(Int32.Parse(System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PORT")));
            });
```